# set the labels of a dataframe using variables R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, label

I have a dataframe where I would like to change the labels, like below:

```
  library(labelled)
  tmp <- diamonds %>% mutate(color = as.character(color)) %>%
    set_value_labels(color = c(E = "white", I = "Red", J = "Black"))
```

This works, but I want to programmatically construct the set the labels (in my case from a database table). For example:

```
  cols <- c("White", "Red", "Black")
  letters <- c("E", "I", "J")
  
  # create the labels vector
  new_labels <- c()
  for(x in 1:3){
    new_labels <- c(new_labels, paste(letters[x], "=", cols[x]))
  }
  
  tmp <- diamonds %>% mutate(color = as.character(color)) %>%
    set_value_labels(color = new_labels)
```

> Error: `labels` must have names.

How do I build the new_labels vector in a format that set_values_labels will understand? Or do it without using library(labelled)

Comment: From which package does the function `set_value_labels()` come from?

Comment: library(labelled) I've updated the question and would be open to other solutions without this library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a named vector using `setNames` and can pass it to  `set_value_labels`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(labelled)

cols <- c("White", "Red", "Black")
letters <- c("E", "I", "J")


tmp <- diamonds %>% 
  mutate(color = as.character(color)) %>%
  set_value_labels(color = setNames(cols, letters))
```